# XAML: insert dashed line at the bottom of every row

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, lines

I am currently using xaml and how do I insert dashed line at the bottom of every row in a grid tag. I was able to insert it one by one using the code below.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    X1="10" Y1="0"
    X2="1270" Y2="0"
    Stroke="White" StrokeDashArray="2, 2"
    StrokeThickness="2" />

    <Line Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    X1="10" Y1="0"
    X2="1270" Y2="0"
    Stroke="White" StrokeDashArray="2, 2"
    StrokeThickness="2" />

   <Line Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    X1="10" Y1="0"
    X2="1270" Y2="0"
    Stroke="White" StrokeDashArray="2, 2"
    StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

However, let's say if I have more than 50 rows in my grid and I wouldn't insert the line tag one by one. Is there a possible way to do it using grid.resource style tag?

Comment: do you have some similar content in each cell? if yes, then ItemsControl is probably a better solution. `Line` can be included in ItemTemplate then

Comment: @ASh Similar as in what type?

Comment: similar is the sense that they are repetitive and can be generated from some template. Lines are similar because their only difference is Grid.Row. Btw , you can at least use Style for each Line, and set Stroke, X2 in setters, instead of writing them on each element

Comment: @ASh thank you so much. I tried it using itemcontrol and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> let's say if I have more than 50 rows in my grid

That means you are doing something wrong. You should use any of ItemsControls in this case. If you really need Grid with 50 rows, you could add your dashed lines in a loop in CodeBehind. Assuming you are using MVVM, CodeBehind is still a proper place to modify GUI.

Comment: Understood. Now Im using codebehind to insert rows into the grid by using ItemControls. Thanks for the reply btw